# Learning Python - TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, tic-tac-toe

I am trying my best to learn Python as I recently switched my major and have become infatuated with the world of Computer Science! I genuinely enjoy it however there are times where like a lot of people do get stuck. I am currently doing a Udemy course and trying to tackle one of the first milestones, however it seems like everything comes out accordingly but... results to error... What I have in mind is not complete yet however I do like to test it from time to time just to make sure everything is going according to plan.

I get the following error yet it still gives me the result...
Please if anyone has any tips or suggestions that they can give to a beginner that would be much appreciated! (First Post! Be Nice! :')  )

```
     | | 
     | | 
     | | 
    Player 1 are you X or O? X
    Please Input a Number 1-9: 6
     | | 
     | |O
     | | 
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:/Users/Danny/Desktop/Python/Python Bootcamp/Milestones/TicTacToe.py", line 76, in <module>
        display(gameon_Board)
      File "C:/Users/Danny/Desktop/Python/Python Bootcamp/Milestones/TicTacToe.py", line 17, in display
        print(board[7]+'|'+board[8]+'|'+board[9])
    TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

**CODE BELOW**

```
"""This is a TIC TAC TOE GAME!
    
You need to do the following...

We need to print a board.
Take in player input.
Place their input on the board.
Check if the game is won,tied, lost, or ongoing.
Repeat c and d until the game has been won or tied.
Ask if players want to play again.

Good Luck! """

#Display Board

def display(board):
    print(board[7]+'|'+board[8]+'|'+board[9])
    print(board[4]+'|'+board[5]+'|'+board[6])
    print(board[1]+'|'+board[2]+'|'+board[3])

#Sets up player markers
def player_Marker():
    marker = ' '
    while marker != 'X' and marker != 'O':
        marker = input("Player 1 are you X or O? ")
        
    player1 = marker
    
    if player1 == 'X':
        player2 = 'O'
    else:
        player2 = 'X'
    
    return (player1,player2)

#Takes User Position Input On Board
def player_Choice():
    position = 'wrong'
    while position not in range(1,10):
        position = int(input("Please Input a Number 1-9: "))  
    
    return position

#Tack on Inputs to Board

# CLEAN_Board = ['#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ']

gameon_Board = ['#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ']

def boardUP(board,position):
    turn = 1
    if turn == 1:
        gameon_Board[position] = player1_Marker
        turn = turn - 1
    if turn == 0:
        gameon_Board[position] = player2_Marker
        turn += 1

    return display(gameon_Board)


# All Together

game_on = True
gameon_Board = ['#',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ']

while game_on:
    display(gameon_Board)
    
    player1_Marker , player2_Marker = player_Marker()
    
    position = player_Choice()

    gameon_Board = boardUP(gameon_Board,position)

    display(gameon_Board)
```

Comment: Your returned value from `boardUP` is a `None` which you are then passing to `display` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`display()` doesn't return anything, it just prints the board. So the default return value is `None`.

But `boardUP()` ends with `return display(gameon_Board)`, so it's returning that `None` value.

And then you assign this result back to the variable with

```
gameon_Board = boardUP(gameon_Board,position)
```

So after the first iteration, `gameon_Board` no longer contains the list of board elements, it contains `None`. And then when you try to access its subscripts you get an error.

Also, you pass the board as an argument to `boardUP`, but it never uses it; it uses the global variable instead. You should use the parameter.

Change the function to:

```
def boardUP(board,position):
    turn = 1
    if turn == 1:
        board[position] = player1_Marker
        turn = turn - 1
    if turn == 0:
        board[position] = player2_Marker
        turn += 1

    display(board)
    return board
```